# Serilog.Sinks.Oracle - Write Log to Oracle DB with Serilog from C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, serilog

I want to write logs to console, file and Oracle DB, from my program (.Net Framework).
I was able to write a log to the console and to a file.
And I can't write to the DB.
My code:

```
    {
        public static readonly ILogger _log;
        static SerilogClass()
        {
            string logsFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logsFolder"];
            string environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environment"];
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

            _log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.File(
                        path: Path.Combine(logsFolder, $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_}.log"),
                        outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:Ij}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                        retainedFileCountLimit: null,
                        shared: true)
                    .WriteTo.Oracle(connection, "Logs")
                    .CreateLogger();
        }
      }
```

How can I write the log to Oracle DB?
I would be happy to advices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this package `Serilog.Sinks.Oracle` and you can get information about it from [here](https://github.com/lucascebertin/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle). This is still under early development phase, so use this code on your own risk.

Database Script:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.LOG(
  "Id"                 INT             NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "Message"            CLOB            NULL,
  "MessageTemplate"    CLOB            NULL,
  "Level"              NVARCHAR2(128)  NULL,
  "TimeStamp"          TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
  "Exception"          CLOB            NULL,
  "Properties"         CLOB            NULL,
  "LogEvent"           CLOB            NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.LOG_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

-- YOU CAN CHOOSE TO USE FUNCTION OR CREATE A TRIGGER... I PREFER THE TRIGGER WAY :) 
-- TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER 
    YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.LOG_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON 
    YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.LOG 
REFERENCING 
    NEW AS NEW 
    OLD AS old 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF :new."Id" IS NULL THEN 
        SELECT 
            YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.LOG_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL 
        INTO 
            :new."Id" 
        FROM dual; 
    END IF; 
END;


-- OR FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.get_seq RETURN INT IS
BEGIN
  RETURN YOUR_TABLE_SPACE.LOG_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

How to use into .net app:

```
  //Don't forget to add the namespace, ok?

  var connectionString =
      "Your Oracle DB conn string";

  // If you choose to use the trigger just pass string.Empty in function name argument (tableSpaceAndFunctionName)
  var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
      .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg => 
          cfg.WithSettings(connectionString)
          .UseBurstBatch() // or if you want to use PeriodicBatch, call .UsePeriodicBatch()
          .CreateSink())
      .CreateLogger();

  const string column = "ADDITIONALDATACOLUMN";
  var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
  {
      AdditionalDataColumns = new List<DataColumn>
      {
          new DataColumn(column , typeof(string))
      }
  };

  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      //.Enrich.FromLogContext() /* uncomment this line if you want to store dynamic values and passing them by LogContext.PushProperty(name, value)... remember, this PushProperty is Disposable*/
      //.Enrich.WithProperty("column", "constant value, lika machine's hostname")  /* uncomment this line if you want to store a "constant value" */
      .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
      .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
          cfg.WithSettings(logConnectionString, columnOptions: columnOptions)
          .UseBurstBatch()
          .CreateSink())
      .CreateLogger();


  //Be aware of the batch limit and delay time configured up here!
  logger.Debug("Yey, this message will be stored on Oracle!!");
```